# How to make composition for compiler in C++?

Tags: c++, bison

I make compiler for c++ and I arrive to code generation level (by MIPS) and I want to generate composition

In YACC the rule of composition is:

```
variable:
object_access
|.....some rule not important here
;
object_access:
variable '.' name 
|.....some rule not important here
;
```

When the input is:

```
class screw
{
int number;
screw();
}
class wheel
{
int type;
screw scw;// here composition
wheel();
}
class car
{
string model;
wheel whl;// here composition
}
void main()
{
car vec=new car();
cout<<vec.whl.scw.number;
}
```

When I visited the object_access node (to generate the code) I can get (variable && name)

My problem is:

When I have like (vec.whl.scw.number) I don't knew the length of (vec.whl.scw.number)  because it work recursion left. I need to the length because (we knew if I load the (vec, whl, scw), I will get the address but if I load the (number) I will get an integer value.

So if I visited the object_access node recursion I only need to load the address of whl by the address of vec and put it in ($t1 ..for example), and then I load the address of scw by the address of whl and put it in ($t1 ..for example), but the (number is not object here I must not save it in ($t1) )..

My problem: how I can knew the last name in object_access node to stop load address? I need to $t1 save the last address in object_access node because I will need it to another operation.

Comment: thats a very long sentence... could you please use some punctuation to make it readable?

Comment: is it clear now @tobi303 ???

Comment: Hi there. If you're posting from a mobile phone, which in turn in causing you to write in lower case and txtspk, please use something easier to type on. We do appreciate a bit of effort in questions here - thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use your symbol table to knew the type of each name in your (object-access) ... all name you need to save them as address there type is (name (name of there class)...I.e not int or double...) only the variable (number ) in your sample have (int or double or 
any type except  type name)
so you can knew if you arrive to number by it's type from symbol table